# Admittance, Conductance, Susceptance definition

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, resistance, frequency, impedance

Admittance is the reciprocal of impedance. But:

1) Susceptance is the reciprocal of reactance, or the imaginary part of admittance ?

2) Conductance is the reciprocal of resistance, or the real part of admittance?

Comment: This is answered on the Wikipedia page on [susceptance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Susceptance).